# adding comboxitems inside wpf listview

Tags: wpf, listview, combobox

I have a listview on the leftside of my wpf screen. When clicked it is supposed to navigate to other portions of application. Now I want to display a cascading menu horizontally(i.e. in right direction) when clicking a listview item. How can i do this programatically?? I have tried placing combobox inside listview item selected event but still it doesn't work. I have also tried comboboxitem.But there appears to be a dead end

Home
                    Class
                    Students Fee Structure
                    List of Students who paid Fee
                    List of Students whose fee is remaining
                    
                
                    
                    
                
@Blachshma

Comment: Did you try using a [ContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.aspx)?

Comment: Context menu also doesn't work.....Can i have any other solutions??

Comment: Why don't you explain **why** it *"doesn't work"* ?

Comment: @Blachshma This code doesn't work .....Am i missing something?? private void ListViewItem_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ContextMenu cntmnu = new ContextMenu();
            cntmnu.Items.Add("Hello");
            
         

        }

Comment: `cntmnu.IsOpen = true;` for starters

Comment: @Blachshma I want similar property for listview item like there is IsOpen property for context menu. One thing I forgot to mention the right side of my window contains frame. Is frame the source of problem??Is it because frame lies in same place where the cascading menu is to be displayed that cascading menu cannot be displayed??

Comment: Please post your existing code / xaml in your original question. It's too hard to make out what you have and what you're trying to achieve